# unable to change screen resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution

I have a Toshiba laptop with 16.04 on it.

The screen resolution is set to 1024 x 768 i.e. 4:3

How can I change it to a 16:9 resolution?

If I go into settings - screen display it says Built-in Display - which is fine but the drop-down box for resolution only has the one option 4:3

```
xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

Help please !

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have used the `nomodeset` option, would you?

Comment: d'oh - I can be so slow !  -  yes   -  nomodeset was left from when I was using the AMD fglrx driver on 15:10

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `nomodeset` option from GRUB's config.

Answer (score 1):

nomodeset was left from when I was using the AMD fglrx driver on 15:10

This has now been removed and the full selection of screen resolutions are now available within settings